# What DLNA server to choose?

Tags: server, dlna

What DLNA server program should I choose and how do I set it up?
It is an absolute requirement that it doesn't take a lot of resources since it will be running on a 500 MHz machine.

There seems to be quite a few server programs and I don't have any experience with these userfriendly auto-detecet protocols/services.

Btw, the server doesn't have a GUI...

Comment: Alright, that's going on my Fit-PC1 as well!

Comment: I've got most of my stuff on an iMac and the TVMobili one works well for me.

Comment: UniversalMediaServer has a [comparison of DLNA server software](http://www.universalmediaserver.com/comparison/).

Comment: Ubuntu 19.10’s new ‘Media Sharing’ toggle in Settings > Sharing means there’s no need to download and install a separate DLNA server to share media photos, videos and music over your local network, see [Ubuntu 19.10: How to share media to your TV, games consoles, etc without installing a third-party client?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1185239/ubuntu-19-10-how-to-share-media-to-your-tv-games-consoles-etc-without-install)

Answer (score 13, accepted):

[MediaTomb](http://mediatomb.cc)?

Quite popular and only a web interface to speak of. It also does on-the-fly transcoding but you may need to disable that or your little 500mhz server might explode.

---

#### Edit

**MediaTomb** is unsupported since *2017-04-03*.
They direct users to [Gerbera](http://gerbera.io), which is built upon **MediaTomb**.

Comment: Actually MediaTomb can transcode on the 500MHz Geode in there, but I have to let it buffer for quite some time (and be sure to close cpu/mem comsuming apps on there as well)

Comment: MediaTomb is no longer supported. [Version 0.12.1 dates from April 8, 2010](http://mediatomb.cc/changelog.txt). Moreover, I ran into [a bug](http://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/mediatomb/+bug/488318) that filled my hard disk partition with a huge log file.

Answer (score 20):

I've switched from MediaTomb (which has been crashing all over the place) to MiniDLNA.
It's lighter, no interface at all and hasn't crashed on me yet. Scans fast too.

[image: Install via the software center]

Comment: How is "no interface at all" an advantage?

Comment: @DanDascalescu I should have said "alternative interface", like a web frontend. My experience was MediaTomb which seemed to focus more on the webapp than a solid UPnP interface. That's what mattered most to me. MiniDLNA delivered.

Answer (score 5):

I'm a fan of `ushare` myself: [GeeXboX uShare UPnP A/V Media Server HomePage](http://ushare.geexbox.org/)

Comment: What do you like about it?

Answer (score 3):

I'm pretty pleased with PS3MediaServer on Ubuntu 11.10. Ubuntu has a help page for it at [Ubuntu Documentation - Ps3MediaServer](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Ps3MediaServer). Installation is easy, adding files is easy and it works great. Don't let the name fool you, you don't have to have a PS3 to enjoy this. And best of all, it's all handled through a graphical GUI.

Answer (score 1):

Plex recently appeared in the Ubuntu Software Center. I have used their server for two years and recommend it.

Comment: Plex is no longer in the Ubuntu Software Center.

Answer (score 1):

Go for Rygel. It is easy to use and does transcoding on the fly (read you can play your videos on your TV if your TV can decode them).

Answer (score 0):

A few more alternatives can be found in my answer to [minidlna and samsung tv file format doesn't support](https://askubuntu.com/questions/313275/68291), e.g. *Rygel* (in the repos), *Mediatomb*, *Serviio*, *PS3Mediaserver*...