# Stream video from Ubuntu server to Android device

Tags: server, android, stream

I have a headless Ubuntu 12.04 server. I have a lot of video on the server. Most of it is in x264 in .mkv. I have a Samsung Nexus phone, and a Nexus 7 tablet.

What are my options when it comes to streaming from the Ubuntu server to Android? I got smb up and running. Some friends of mine were talking about DLNA, the "Playstation media server" could be a solution?

Answer (score 8):

### Serving over plain HTTP

The simplest possible solution is HTTP on the server in combination with an Android client with a video player that can do HTTP streaming, such as [VLC](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=org.videolan.vlc), [Nova Video Player](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=org.courville.nova), [mpv for android](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=is.xyz.mpv), [MxPlayer](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.mxtech.videoplayer.ad) (ad-supported). There are plenty HTTP servers to choose from:

Here are some one liners.

#### Python 2.x (❗️no seek support)

```
$ python -m SimpleHTTPServer 8000
```

#### Python 3.x (❗️no seek support)

```
$ python -m http.server 8000
```

#### Twisted (Python)

First, install the twisted package if not already present with `pip install -U twisted` (`pip3 install -U twisted`), then:

```
$ twistd -n web -p 8000 --path .
```

After you start the web server, open the browser on your Android device and type the IP and port of your Ubuntu box e.g. http://192.168.1.123:8000

You can use `ifconfig` on Ubuntu to see the IP address.

A more extended list of HTTP oneliner servers: https://gist.github.com/willurd/5720255

#### Caddyserver

My preferred choice is [`caddy`](https://caddyserver.com/) with the built-in [`file-server`](https://caddyserver.com/docs/caddyfile/directives/file_server) plugin. Caddy is written in Go and unlike the python options above is production level software, works faster and can do range requests that will allow to seek videos. Start caddy with:

```bash
caddy file-server --listen :2030 --browse --root /
```

> The line `:2030` will make caddy listen on port `2030` so you you'll be able to access it at something like http://192.168.1.100:2030 (replace with the correct IP).

> <sup>If needed, with `caddy` you can also enable basic authentication.</sup>

#### Samba server-side + VLC/Kodi client-side

If you need to access your ubuntu box in a home network then you can also [enable Samba on the Ubuntu server](https://ubuntu.com/tutorials/install-and-configure-samba) and then on your client device (Android/Linux/Mac/Windows) add an SMB share as in the [SAMBA HOWTO — search for **Add SMB share to Kodi Method 1|2**](https://forum.kodi.tv/showthread.php?tid=362113). Kodi can also generate previews and fetch IMDB info for your movies if that's what you are after.

VLC (mobile versions) will be able to discover and browse your Samba shares without extra fiddling. Desktop OS's normally have built-in support for samba shares so you can browse them pretty much like a local file system.

#### Client-side caddy-based media browser

Given that `caddy`'s `file-server` built-in plugin can also return a directory listing as JSON I created a client-side media browser that is pure js+html and only requires `caddy` to be running on the server with a custom `Caddyfile`. It's more of a proof-of-concept project and not meant for anything serious:

- https://github.com/glowinthedark/mediabro4caddy

It works in the browser and will only play video formats that the browsers can play, so no proper MKV support.

Comment: This is epic dude

Comment: This man deserves a medal (Or May be a bounty). The answer is epic simple

Comment: very simple technique worked ! but not able to forward videos

Comment: @AbhishekKamal: `SimpleHTTPServer` does not support `range` requests. If you need seek support for videos you might want to use https://github.com/danvk/RangeHTTPServer or other, more advanced servers.

Comment: _After trying `python -m SimpleHTTPServer 8000` i found that i can't seek videos so i stopped `python -m SimpleHTTPServer 8000` and used an another trick, The trick is.... whenever i want to stream videos from laptop to android, i use **smplayer** (**video player, newest version 19.1.0**) in laptop, it provides a barcode, then i scan that barcode from the phone and i success to seek videos. And I found that, this method is working faster than previous._

Answer (score 5):

On your Android Device you will have to install a [DLNA client](https://play.google.com/store/search?q=dlna%20client&c=apps) to be able to access media shares you have on your server.

On your server you will have to run a DLNA/UPnP server that makes the shares accessible. Your network settings need to allow UPnP and Multicast (check with your router).

There are [several solutions](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1755/what-dlna-server-to-choose) for an UPnP server you can choose from. With [**MiniDLNA**](http://sourceforge.net/projects/minidlna/), a leightweight but powerful DLNA server we able to stream MKV, and x264 content. This application is my recommendation for running on a headless server.

We can install it from the repositories with

```
sudo apt-get install minidlna
```

For help on setting it up see: https://help.ubuntu.com/community/MiniDLNA

Comment: Worth noting would be that not every version of Android supports all kinds media formats. While newer devices with version 4.0+ support the most common formats, older versions and processors with limited feature sets may have issues here and there. On top of that device manufacturers can still mess up the platforms default format support. Of course Android offers players that do decoding in software, but thats mostly a workaround and costs battery life. http://developer.android.com/guide/appendix/media-formats.html

Answer (score 4):

On your **server**:

- Install *minidlna*:  `sudo apt-get install minidlna`
- Configure `/etc/minidlna.conf`

On your **android devide**:

- Install *bubbleupnp* or any other dlna/upnp client
- Select your server

Answer (score 2):

For media streaming using the UPnP media server specifications, I would look at:

1. **Mediatomb** - runs in the background serving media, has a web interface which you can use to build the library.
2. **Kodi** - normally used as a client, but you can enable media serving under the Network options within it.

You can find both in the **Software Center**.

As far as Android clients go, there are ports of both **VLC** and **Kodi**.