# Connect Bluetooth headphones through my mobile phone to my PC

Tags: bluetooth, headphones

My phone has Bluetooth.

Is there a way to connect Bluetooth headphones through my mobile phone to my PC i.e. use my mobile phone as Bluetooth dongle?

I can connect the phone to my PC using a USB cable.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Stream video from ubuntu server to Android device](https://askubuntu.com/questions/181751/stream-video-from-ubuntu-server-to-android-device)

Comment: @mbeyss OP is asking about using the phone as a Bluetooth dongle, not sending video to the phone.

Comment: @wjandrea yes, thank you. I've updated question to be more clarified.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The easiest way would be to use the [SoundWire](http://georgielabs.net/) commercial sound server for your Ubuntu PC together with [their app](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.georgie.SoundWire&hl=en) to stream the audio to your android device.

In a separate step, you would use the usual device-specific way to redirect the Android audio output to your BT headphones.

The Android app is available in Free and Pro versions. The Free version interrupts your audio every 45 minutes or so.