# Stream my movies to my Nexus7 and other devices?

Tags: kubuntu, streaming

I am running Kubuntu 12.10 and have a 350gb hard drive that has a bunch of videos on it and I am wondering if it is possible to stream the movies over my local network.
I think it would be really cool if there was a way to do this so I could wathc the movies wherever I want on my Nexus 7.  Is this possible?  Does it make sense what I'm looking to do?

Thanks in advance,

Jonathan

Comment: I prefer [PS3 Media Server](http://www.ps3mediaserver.org/) myself, but check out http://askubuntu.com/questions/1755/what-dlna-server-to-choose for a question on Media Servers.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We sucessfully stream video to our Android devices with a combination of

- [minidlna](https://apps.ubuntu.com/cat/applications/minidlna) [image: Install minidlna]
  on our content server and
- [Bubble UPnP](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.bubblesoft.android.bubbleupnp&hl=de) on the Android device.

After installation of minidlna you will have to edit the configuration file `/etc/minidlna.conf` (as root) to give your media content directories:

```
media_dir=V,/home/<user>/Videos  # for video content
```

The streaming service will be run or stopped with

```
sudo service minidlna start
sudo service minidlna stop
sudo service minidlna restart  # for changes in config to take effect
```

See also:

- [Ubuntu Community Wiki: MiniDLNA](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/MiniDLNA)
- [MiniDLNA Application Indicator](https://askubuntu.com/a/175891/3940)

As an alternative you can also stream media content with [vlc](https://apps.ubuntu.com/cat/applications/vlc) [image: Install vlc], available for both, Kubuntu, and Android.

Comment: Perfect this works just like I wanted it to.  Great job