# Stream media from Ubuntu 12.04 to Xbox One

Tags: streaming, mediaserver

Not sure if this is an Ubuntu question, but I've posted in Xbox forums too, so hopefully I'll get some help!

As the title says, I'm looking for a way to stream media from my Ubuntu 12.04 laptop to my Xbox One console.. any ideas?

I've done a bit of research, and so far I can see that the Xbox One only supports playing media from a dlna server via a 'play to' feature, i.e. it can't pull files from the server, the files need to be pushed from the server (my laptop) to the console, so I was wondering if there is anything that will work on Ubuntu that will give me this feature..

Comment: So you want to stream media live, or just copy the files over to be played on the Xbox?

Comment: @wilf OP wants to access a media server with his Xbox

Comment: @searchfgold6789 - but the last bit is about copying files... :S

Comment: What's wrong with the DLNA server solutions already proposed in other questions? http://askubuntu.com/questions/1755/what-dlna-server-to-choose/112480#112480

Comment: @LiveWireBT Those DLNA servers don't give me the ability to push the file to my Xbox One, which is needed, as unlike the X360, the XB1 doesn't have the ability of browsing the files shared by my laptop via the consoles file explorer.. I've read that it is possible to use ps3mediaserver combined with bubbleupnp but to push the files to my console i need the bubbleupnp app for android/iOS, neither of which is an option for me - Yes I'm one of the minority who doesn't have a phone with either of those OS's

Comment: If you like, you can ask in [softwarerecs.se] for one solution that fits your needs. Remember that they will [ask to follow their quality standards.](http://meta.softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/336/what-is-required-for-a-question-to-contain-enough-information)