# Ubuntu Kodi and Fire Stick

Tags: nfs, kodi, amazon

I'm new to this kodi software media center stuff.

I have a desktop w Ubuntu which gets internet via an ethernet port in a wifi router (from the cable tv company). Kodi is also installed on the desktop.

I have the (tiny) amazon fire-stick connected to my TV in living room. I've sideloaded Kodi onto it. The firestick is active on my home wifi.

I want to stream vids stored on my Desktop Ubuntu HDD, on to the firestick connected to the TV. (both have kodi installed)

How can i do this? I'm interested in knowing if some of the kodi file sharing protocols (like NFS) will work over the wifi router to firestick? which sharing protocol should i use?

Answer (score 2):

Kodi media center has many options for displaying audio and video content streamed from another network source.

In case Kodi was installed on the receiver **and** the media server we can just use Kodi's inbuilt UPnP media server feature. This can be done by enabling *"Share my libraries"* in *[Settings > Services > UPnP](http://kodi.wiki/view/Settings/Services/UPnP_DLNA)*.

Other than that any Kodi instance can also access network shares in case we had allowed sharing our media directories. Needless to say that any other [DLNA server](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1755/what-dlna-server-to-choose) available in the network can be accessed from a Kodi client.

We use miniDLNA running on our media server for a Kodi client attached to our TV.

Comment: Ah. I see that i don't necessarily need kodi on the server side to share files to a kodi client. I was confusing file sharing with kodi itself. Simply sharing a folder on the desktop should make it visible to the firestick's kodi app, then. will do it.