# Ubuntu Plex and Amazon Firestick

Tags: webserver, multimedia, plex, mediaserver, amazon

I'm new to this plex software media center stuff.

I have a desktop w Ubuntu which gets internet via an ethernet port in a wifi router (from the cable tv company). Plex is installed on the desktop.

I have the (tiny) amazon fire-stick connected to my TV in living room.  The firestick is active on my home wifi.

I want to stream vids stored on my Desktop Ubuntu HDD, on to the firestick connected to the TV.

How can i do this with `plex`?  This seems [generally](https://www.pcmag.com/how-to/how-to-share-your-plex-libraries) possible as:

> Enter the username or email address of the person you want to share
> your library with, and click on the user when it pops up. In the next
> window, choose which libraries you share with others. To share all of
> them, select your server and click Save. Or select only the libraries
> you want to share, then click Save.
>
> The person you're sharing with should then get an email invitation to
> access your library. Once accepted, they can pull up your libraries in
> any Plex app. If they (or you) have access to multiple servers, they
> can manually switch between them or search across all servers.

with the proviso that I'm exclusively interested in files physically on the local hard drive.

---

(question is [almost](https://askubuntu.com/q/827200/45156) a duplicate to a kodi question, but with `plex` instead.)

(The tv and and pc are too far away for `hdmi` for what that's worth.)

Answer (score 1):

The easy way is to point your Firestick's web browser at the Plex web page. Plex will allow library selection and play media in the browser window (with fullscreen option).

A slightly more complex way is to enable UPnP in Plex settings, then any VLC player (or any other UPnP-aware player) on your home network can detect and browse your library.