# Ubuntu 19.10: How to share media to your TV, games consoles, etc without installing a third-party client?

Tags: 19.10, sharing, mediaserver, dlna, upnp

How is it possible to share media to your TV, games consoles, etc without installing a third-party client (e.g. DLNA/UPnP client Rygel) in Ubuntu 19.10?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ubuntu 19.10’s new ‘Media Sharing’ toggle in `Settings > Sharing` means there’s **no need to download and install a separate DLNA/UPnP server** to share media photos, videos and music over your local network (Source: [OMG Ubuntu](https://www.omgubuntu.co.uk/2019/10/ubuntu-dlna-media-sharing-server)). It is great to have this out-of-the-box - I have used several tools over the past years and it was not always as easy to configure than this.

1. To **activate** media sharing in Ubuntu 19.10 just pop open the main Settings app and select the ‘Sharing’ option in the sidebar:
   [image]
2. **Click on the ‘Media Sharing’ option** that’s greyed out in the main pane. A small modal dialogue will appear:
   [image]
3. Slide the switcher in the header bar of the modal dialogue to ‘On’, and then **select** a **network** from the list to share your media on. 
   *Disclaimer: DLNA sharing isn’t a secure way to share media. Everyone on the same network can access (but not edit/delete) shared media.*
4. You’ll notice that 3 folders are shared by default: Pictures, Videos and Music. **If you don’t want to share one/any of these just remove them** from the list using the x ion to the right of the folder name.
5. **To add your own media sources** just scroll down the dialogue and hit the + button. Then use the folder picker to navigate to and select a different folder on your system. Repeat the process to add additional directories.

After the activation, there can be some **higher cpu use** depending on how much files you want to be able to share. The `mx-tracker` crawls through the system to find them and it can take a while depending on the size of your media library.

If the sharing is **not working**, check whether the right network (step 3) is selected.
In case you have a **problem or found a bug**, report a bug or ask a question on the [Rygel Launchpad page](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/rygel).

**For more details,** please read [the article on OMG Ubuntu](https://www.omgubuntu.co.uk/2019/10/ubuntu-dlna-media-sharing-server).